# How to do pairwise word-count in Scala using DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql, rdd, word-count

I have a data frame (df) like this:

```
tweets
------
rain rain go away
train on the way
```

My expected output (**any format is fine**)

```
((rain,rain),1) ((rain,go),2) (rain,away),2) ((go,away),1)
((train,on),1) ((train,the),1) ((thain,way),1) ((on,the),1) ((on,way),1) ((the,way),1)
```

I converted the df to RDD to apply map and reduceByKey method but couldn't get the expected results. I can easily convert the `Array[((String, String), Int)]` results to df but I need help to produce the correct result first.

**Update 2018-08-18**

Actually, my ultimate result should be like this as a DataFrame:

```
word1    word2    count
-----    -----    -----
rain     rain       1
rain     go         2
rain     away       2
go       away       1
train    on         1
train    the        1
train    way        1
on       the        1
on       way        1
the      way        1
```

Can you help, please? It can be noted that all answers work for small dataset but fail when I apply this to a huge amount of data.

Answer (score 3):

You can apply `rdd` to the DataFrame, index the split strings using `zipWithIndex` into an array, apply `combinations(2)` to assemble the word-pair combinations, and group each row in the RDD by the actual words to count the size of the resulting Map values:

```
val df = Seq(
  "rain rain go away",
  "train on the way"
).toDF("tweets")

val rdd = df.
  rdd.map(_.getString(0)).
  map( _.split("\\s+").zipWithIndex.combinations(2).toList ).
  map( _.groupBy(a => (a(0)._1, a(1)._1)).mapValues(_.size).toList )

rdd.collect
// res1: Array[List[((String, String), Int)]] = Array(
//   List(((rain,rain),1), ((go,away),1), ((rain,go),2), ((rain,away),2)),
//   List(((the,way),1), ((on,the),1), ((on,way),1), ((train,way),1), ((train,the),1), ((train,on),1))
// )
```

Note that the "indexing" step of the words is to differentiate identical words prior to generating the combinations so that, for example, the two occurrences of ("rain", "go") in the pairing combinations won't be collapsed into one.

An alternative approach in generating the word-pair combinations is via `for-comprehension`, as suggested in the comments section:

```
val rdd = df.
  rdd.map(_.getString(0)).
  map{ row => 
    val words = row.split("\\s+")
    val sz = words.size
    for(i <- 0 until sz; j <- i + 1 until sz) yield (words(i), words(j))
  }.
  map( _.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size).toList )
```

Comment: great, thanks a lot! could you please tell me how can combine the counts for the pair like ((go,away),1) and ((away,go),3) together like ((away,go),4)?

Comment: @Abu Shoeb, I think I misinterpreted your question as counting consecutive word pairs for the entire RDD.  Having reread your expected output, you seem to want combinations of all word pairs per row.  Please see my revised answer.

Comment: Interesting idea with `zipWithIndex`, but basically makes `combinations` kind of useless. I would resort to something boring like `for(i <- 0 until words.length; j <- i + 1 until words.length) yield((words(i), words(j)))` after split.

Comment: @Victor Moroz, I also like the approach of using `for-comprehension` which might be slightly more verbose but does produce a simpler dataset for the following `groupBy`.  Thanks.

Comment: The `for-comprehension` works really fast when it is applied to a huge amount of data. Thanks! Btw, could you tell me how can I get `Array[((String, String), Int)]` instead of `Array[List[((String, String), Int)]]`? Or can I get the result in DF directly?

Comment: @LeoC no no, you didn't misunderstand. Your first solution was the right answer I was looking for. Later, I realized the problem of ((away,go),3) and ((away,go),4) so asked you again. Thanks

Comment: @Abu Shoeb, to flatten the RDD to type `Array[T]` instead of `Array[List[T]]`, you can simply replace the last `map` with `flatMap`.  i.e. `flatMap( _.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size).toList )`

Comment: @LeoC that's the main problem I originally had. Whenever I use flapMap and apply this to a huge amount of data I get this error : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 2 in stage 10.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 2.0 in stage 10.0 (TID 45, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not able to reproduce the said problem.  If `map` works but switching it to `flatMap` doesn't, perhaps try chaining a `flatMap(identity)` at the end instead.  If that doesn't help, I would suggest that you post a separate question with just the part of the code that causes the problem along with a minimal sample dataset that can reproduce it.

Comment: Ok @LeoC. Please help me with the last step. Now I have `RDD[((String, String), Int)]`. So when I convert this to dataframe using `toDF()` it gives me a dataframe like `{"_1":"rain","_2":"rain"}  1`. How can I get it as col1,col2,col3 like `rain   rain   2' instead of two columns where col1 has nested values like rain,rain   2? Thanks

Comment: Given a `RDD[((String, String), Int)]`, you can transform the converted DataFrame like `rdd.toDF("wordpair", "count").select($"wordpair._1".as("w1"), $"wordpair._2".as("w2"), $"count")`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sorted` function to `count` same `groups` but in different order like below

```
//df

+--------------------+
|              tweets|
+--------------------+
|rain rain go away go|
|    train on the way|
+--------------------+

//Solution Approach

 import org.apache.spark.mllib.rdd.RDDFunctions._

 df.rdd.flatMap(_.getString(0).split(" ")).sliding(2).map(_.sorted).map(arr=>((arr(0),arr(1))->1)).reduceByKey(_+_).collect

//Output: 

res13: Array[((String, String), Int)] = Array(((rain,rain),1), ((on,train),1), ((on,the),1), ((go,rain),1), ((go,train),1), ((away,go),2), ((the,way),1))
```